# PhoneGap UI Investigation

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, dojo

I am investigating creating cross platform mobile apps using PhoneGap.

I have looked at JQuery Mobile and dojo for UI components.

What other ones are out there? So far I am impressed with both, but they leave me looking for more.

The reason is that JQuery Mobile doesn't look very native. Dojo looks more native for the layout and graphics aren't quite right in my mind. For instance the back button is the same height as the header on Android (assuming I am using it right).

Comment: jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch and then Dojo are the 3 most popular ones I see mentioned on the PhoneGap Google group. Each has it's own pluses and minuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) quite interesting.

Comment: Leaning towards jQuery Mobile at the moment though.

Answer (score 0):

The one I use for my app is ionic

http://ionicframework.com/

quick and easy uses Angular JS